# Differential pair in Altium

Tags: altium

I have a difficulty with Altium giving me an error when I try to create a differential pair. I have placed my signal into blanket and created a net in the schematic. I also added differential pair directive pointing the two signal named with _N and _P

When I generate the ECO, Altium tells me this: "number of nets in differential pair is 1 instead of 2"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Those are the screenshot of how the parameters are input.

[image]

Comment: I fall into the same error.
I configured in the same way but it remains the same message.
someone helps me and thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your differential pair nets must be named the EXACT same except for the _N and _P at the end. Yours are different--You have PCM_SPK1P_UG96_P and PCM_SPK1N_UG96_N. The "SPK1P" and "SPK1N" need to be the same (i.e. "SPK1").

I suggest naming your nets as follows:

PCM_SPK1_UG96_P

PCM_SPK1_UG96_N

Comment: oh, I see the issue now. Thank you very much for this, I know I have to name them the same but didn't see the problem...

Comment: Somewhat related question: does Altium have a mechanism for creating a differential pair with arbitrarily named nets?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Good question. To my knowledge, no it does not. The P and N conductors for a differential pair must have the same name except for the _P and _N suffix.