# Altium Differential Pairs, nets not found

Tags: altium

Question is similar to [Differential pair in altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240436/differential-pair-in-altium) but different (not a duplicate)

Hi !
When about to ECO the schematic to PCB (**Design > Update PCB**), errors shows up showing that "net(s) not found in differential pair" for my nets.

Even though, the nets are named properly (same name, *only _N and _P changes*) and both nets have the *DIFFPAIR*. Still getting the error.

Example screenshot :

[image]

note that *_* (underscore) shows as space because lines are above text.

Gives me this :

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of your Project Options -> Class Generation window.

Comment: Whatever, found the issue. When using Verify, it shows error because the net still hasn't been created. IF you start the ECO, the net gets created and the issue resolves itself. Add an answer if you want

Comment: If you found the solution I recommend you add the answer and mark it as "accepted"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this happens, it is only a visual issue. The nets aren't found because they still aren't created.

You need to apply and not verify or it will not work.